# What is the difference between a def and a lambda'd val?

Tags: scala, lambda

What is the difference between

```
def plusOne(n: Int) = n + 1
```

and

```
val plusOne = (n : Int) => n + 1
```

Comment: http://jim-mcbeath.blogspot.co.uk/2009/05/scala-functions-vs-methods.html

Comment: possible duplicate of [Difference between method and function in Scala](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2529184/difference-between-method-and-function-in-scala)

Comment: @0__: Not a dupe. This is about differences between functions and *`var`s*.

Comment: @Mechanical snail - I see no `var`s. It is method versus function clearly (`val plusOne` holds a function which is equivalent to `plusOne _` defined as method).

Comment: If you don't know the terminology, then the question 'what is the difference between a function and a lambda'd val' becomes irrelevant to you. If I'd know that was what I was asking, I wouldn't have need to ask this question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What the difference really comes down to is that the first is a "method", and the second is a "function", and in Scala these two things are surprisingly different.

You could see, for example, [Difference between method and function in Scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2529184/difference-between-method-and-function-in-scala).

Answer (score 4):

Actually, both of them are functions.

The first one is a method or a local function, depending on where it is declared. The second one is a function value, which is an object instantiated at runtime. Methods, local functions, function values, and function literals are all flavors of functions in Scala.

See here for a chapter of Martin Odersky's book on this topic: http://www.artima.com/pins1ed/functions-and-closures.html